# Rendering nested interpolation in vuejs. Render interpolation that is in a string that is being rendered through interpolation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, interpolation

I have a an object that is being passed down from the server to load and build routes (pages). Within this object i have array that loads all that is going to be on the appropriate page - In summary it's a dynamic page builder. so within that array i have properties (strings) that have vuejs syntax within them.

ie: `title: 'this is the title {{name}}'`

Now `title` property is being passed to the route component and loaded as it should but it's rendering with the interpolation's double curly braces and the variable name. The string contains interpolation {{name}} that i want to have  evaluated and rendered with its actual value, but it's not doing that.

I am trying to figure out a simple way to render out title as well the interpolation `{{name}}` value within it.

I have tried to create a method that matches anything that is being passed within curly braces. But i feel like this is not scalable or ideal as there may be interpolation in nested objects/arrays within the page builder object.

Comment: did you try `title: 'this is the title '+{{name}}`

Comment: Yes i did. I get syntax error. My guess is cause vue syntax does not work in routes being there is no value set for it? the value for `name` is going to be set in the component it is being passed too... I also tried `title: 'this is the title \{\{name\}\}'` with no luck...

Answer (score 0):

Try Javascript string interpolation, something like `title: 'this is title ${title}'`

Important: you have to use backticks instead of quotes.

Mdn reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Oh, and the double curly brace syntax works only in the templates. For all other places (js) you just need to include js variables. Possibly you'd have to use `this.title`.

Comment: Is this relevant for vuejs interpolation?

Comment: Not sure what are you referring to as "vuejs interpolation". It's just the way you can interpolate strings. You have an array with some data and you want to interpolate some of the data, right? I bet you dont do that in your template (or do you?) That's a Javascript thing, vue does not have anything to do with it. There's planty of possible setups some of them having their gotchas. If you'd care to share more code and context it'd be easier to know for sure.